# what's the evaluation order of two conditions (A and B, A or B) in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

For example in `while A and B`, if A is False, it's not necessary to evaluate B. Then will B be evaluated in this case?
Similarly, in `if A or B`, if A is True, it's not necessary to evaluate B.

Specific context is [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/summary-ranges/), I wrote

```
def summaryRanges(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[str]
    """
    output = []

    i = 0

    while ( i < len(nums) ):

        head = nums[i]


        while ( i <= len(nums)-2 ) and (nums[i+1] == nums[i] + 1): ### question here
                i += 1

        tail = nums[i]

        if head == tail:
            output.append(str(head))
        else:
            output.append(str(head) + '->' + str(tail))

        i += 1
```

I don't know if it works yet (troubled by other bugs). In the line commented with 'question here', `(nums[i+1] == nums[i] + 1)` will cause index exceeding string length if `i==len(nums)-1`, so I added `( i <= len(nums)-2 )` trying to prevent that.

Any suggestions on how to fix/avoid/circumvent this is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: @BrenBarn nice thanks! that's what i was looking for. If you could put the answer as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and` and `or` do **short-circuit**. Note that the value of the expression will always be that of one of the operands, and not necessarily `True` or `False`.